# jWplayer does not run stream on Android

Tags: android, jwplayer

Hi I am having some problems in rendering `jwplayer` html5 streams on Android.
I have connected the device to my computer and using the chrome dev tools, I tried to debug the problem.

Apparently when I press the play button a call to this url is trying to be executed

[http://edge07.streamgate.nl/vod/*definst*/content1/END_42569_B.mp4/playlist.m3u](http://edge07.streamgate.nl/vod/_definst_/content1/END_42569_B.mp4/playlist.m3u)

The reason that I am saying that it is trying is because the call does not actually get executed and the status is displayed as canceled.Here is what I mean:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issues with Android and M3U8 natively - http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

However, I have a small work around you can use for this, check the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/8/jwplayer.js"></script>
<center><div id='container'></div></center>
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) != null){
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        file: "http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8",
        type: "mp4",
        primary: "html5"
    });
} else {
jwplayer("container").setup({
  playlist: [{
    image: "http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/gSzpo2wh-480.jpg",
    sources: [{
      file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/s8BPzDe0.smil"
    },{
      file: "http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8"
    }]
  }],
  primary: "flash"
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: can I play my video place on some url using JWPlayer in my Android Native app, if yes can you please help me how to do so?

Comment: You should contact us for information about our SDK. http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/